# No sound coming from laptop headphone on Kali Linux

Tags: linux, audio, drivers, debian, headphone-jack

I'm running Kali Linux 1.1.0 on UEFI mode and I'm in trouble with headphone jack. The speaker works well, but the headphone doesn't have any sound. It worked perfectly before but suddenly the sound on headphone comes off, although I didn't change anything. I had this problem before and every time I had to reinstall Kali to fix it.

So far, I tried: [Fix sound mute in Kali Linux on boot](http://www.blackmoreops.com/2014/01/16/fix-sound-mute-kali-linux-boot/) and [Fix Sound driver on Kali Linux](http://hackerzelite.blogspot.com/2014/03/fix-sound-driver-on-kali-linux.html).

None of these work, does anyone know how to fix it?

p/s: I'm running dual-boot and tried the headphone-jack in Windows, it works perfectly there.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to the Applications icon on the dash dock, search for "settings", then select "sound." This shows you a list of connected audio devices and the integrated ones. Select the appropriate entry.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing Pavucontrol it has a drop down menu to select the used port, also make sure to use alsamixer to activate/deactivate the right device and channels